# Can not build project with FMOD for Unreal 2.0.2.20 for iOS Simulator - Error “building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS”

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, unreal-engine5, fmod

I have Xcode 15.2 + MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1 + iPhone SDK 17.2  + Apple M3 chip

When I build my project with FMOD for Unreal 2.0.2.20 for iOS Simulator on have an error

> /Plugins/FMODStudio/Binaries/IOS/libfmodL_iphoneos.a(libfmodL_iphoneos.a-arm64-master.o)
> building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS,
> file  '/Plugins/FMODStudio/Binaries/IOS/libfmodL_iphoneos.a'

Found that in downloaded latest version "fmodstudio20220ue5.3mac.zip" from https://www.fmod.com/download#fmodforunreal inside folder "Plugins/FMODStudio/Binaries/IOS" there are no files for iOS Simulator (so it's not builded for support it or they just forgot to do it)

HOW TO FIX? here is the answer

So next step from page https://www.fmod.com/download#fmodengine I downloaded “fmodstudioapi20220ios-installer.dmg” inside 2 folders “/api/core/lib” and “/api/studio/lib” I found these files and copy it to my folder “/Plugins/FMODStudio/Binaries/IOS/”, and it didn’t work

So just to try luck I made a copy of this folder and deleted files that work for iOS build only

- libfmod_iphoneos.a
- libfmodL_iphoneos.a
- libfmodstudio_iphoneos.a
- libfmodstudioL_iphoneos.a

Next step renamed files

- libfmod_iphonesimulator.a → libfmod_iphoneos.a
- libfmodL_iphonesimulator.a → libfmodL_iphoneos.a
- libfmodstudio_iphonesimulator.a → libfmodstudio_iphoneos.a
- libfmodstudioL_iphonesimulator.a → libfmodstudioL_iphoneos.a

And finally I successfully builded and launched my project with FMOD for Unreal 2.0.2.20 for iOS Simulator

FMOD team need to rebuild FMOD for Unreal with adding _iphonesimulator and _appletvsimulator files and support and it will launch on iOS/TVOS Simulators with any problems.

PS same you can do with TVOS Simulator and fix it